# Call to a collection path keeps passing an id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a search method in a rails app I'm writing. Here is an excerpt.

The intent is to use regex to match all items with a description which matches a search query . Then, all matching item ids are passed as a string to another page. (this all takes place in a Search controller).

The item controller then catches that string of ids, splits them up into an array and displays a list of the matching objects.

I'm currently getting a problem however, whereby rails is attaching to the redirect_to statement another paramater (which according to the trace is {"id" => "search"} and is then searching for an Item with ID ":a1". It obviously can't find one (ids are all numeric) and therefore the app crashes. Can anyone work out why this is the case?

**IN THE SEARCH CONTROLLER**

```
rquery = Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(@query), Regexp::IGNORECASE)
item_list = []
Item.all.each{|item| item_list << item if rquery.match(item.shortdescr)} 

unless item_list == nil
    ids = ""

    maybe_matters.each do |matter|
        ids += item.id.to_s + " "
    end

    redirect_to search_items_path(ids: ids)
    return
end
```

**IN THE ITEM CONTROLLER**

```
def search
    authorize! :show, Item
    @id = params[:ids].split
    @search = []
    @id.each do |id|
      @search << id.to_i
    end

    @items = Item.accessible_by(current_ability).where(id: @search).order('completed desc nulls last').page params[:page]
end
```

**EDIT**

In case it's relevant, this is (a very small) part of the routes file:

```
resources :items, only: [:index, :show] do
    collection do
        post :search
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend making `search` a GET request. Make sure the path to that action is a collection action in your `routes.rb`. If your controller is named `ItemsController`:

```
resources :items do
  get 'search', on: :collection
end
```

You can pass your search params as a URL parameter:

`GET /items/search?query=searchterm`

**EDIT**

Just realized the POST in your routes. You can't redirect to a POST path which is probably why you're getting weird behavior. Change search action to a GET and the issue will at least be partially resolved.

Also, how are you handling URL encoding? Characters with spaces will get encoded to weird values like `%20` which might give the unexpected results you're seeing when you call stuff like `params[:ids].split`.

If possible, I'd recommend consolidating this into a single controller action rather than redirecting.